# How to handle data type conversation in python?

Tags: python, data-science, data-analysis, data-processing, data-segment

I am doing the data segmentation using python for some csv data. I have below columns like Actionid, name, title.
The data in given column is like;

[image]

Currently I am getting below error

[image]

My code is ;

```
import pandas as pd # for dataframes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # for plotting graphs
import seaborn as sns # for plotting graphs
import datetime as dt

data = pd.read_csv("Mydata.csv")
#pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)

##print (data.head())
##print (data.tail())
##print (filtered_data.Country.value_counts()[:10].plot(kind='bar'))

plt.figure(1, figsize=(15, 6))
n=0

for x in ['actionId','name', 'title']:
    n += 1
    plt.subplot(1,3,n)
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5, wspace=0.5)
    sns.distplot(data[x], bins=20)
    plt.title('Displot of {}'.format(x))
plt.show()
```

Comment: What are you attempting?

Comment: I am trying to get graph for the columns... against each other.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert data in the title column to float right?
You cant do that since there is some text in that column... You can convert a string containing a float say s = '1.234' to a float but you cant convert a string with text in it into a float.

Comment: Thanks! but there should be some way to do it? It may come with any of the columns in different way. There is huge data in csv.

Comment: You can convert if the data contains proper data that can be converted. There is no meaning to convert say "HELLO" into a decimal. If you have a valid string containing numeric value, we can use float() or int() functions to convert. @Amaze_Rock

Comment: Is there anything for special character?

Comment: What do you mean by a special character?

Comment: if special characters comes with number and string.

Comment: OK you have a string containing some characters and some numbers and you want to convert the numeric part alone to a float am I correct? In that case you can either go letter by letter yourself or use the filter method. DM me if you still dont get it : )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233263/discussion-between-mahesh-aravind-v-and-amaze-rock).

Comment: Thanks... I will check your solution... I was busy in some other assignment and was not able to check your response yesterday. Will connect if I am with any queries.. Good Day... TC.